# Pointer Compatibility Confusion

Tags: c

I have read a file into a string, stored the string into a dynamically allocated array. Up till that point, the program works fine. Now I am trying to use the dynamically allocated array to find the position of the second string in the first string.

```
void findwordposition(char word[],int numrows,char*file[numrows])
{
 char **ptr,*pa;
 int i=0;

  for(i=0;i<numrows;i++)
   {
    ptr=&file[i];    
    pa=strstr(ptr,word)(Compiler error regarding pointer compatibility)
   }
 }
```

Can someone please explain me how to use an array of pointers (automatically and dynamically allocated) with string functions and what are the possible reasons behind pointer compatibility errors.

Comment: `char *strstr(char *, char *);` is the signature. `ptr` is `char **`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

[`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) is declared as:

```
char *strstr( const char* str, const char* substr );
```

You need to pass it something that can be converted to those argument types. `ptr` is not one of them since its type is `char **`.

You can use

```
char *ptr,*pa;

...


ptr = file[i];    
pa = strstr(ptr, word);
```

to remove the compile errors.

Hopefully there are no semantic errors in your code and the program will run fine after those changes.

Comment: Thank You, but an array on the right side of an assignment statement implicitly decays to a pointer to its first element (so I thought a pointer to the first element of a pointer would be a pointer to a pointer)? Or does that not apply when one also mentions an array index?

Comment: @AMD, You are right about an array decaying to a pointer. However, I don't see how that is related to your posted code.

Comment: I was thinking file[i] in the above posted answer is of type char**, how come it is of type char*? My reasoning is file[i] is a pointer itself, on the right side of an assignment statement it decays into a pointer, therefore a pointer to a pointer is of type char**?

Comment: @AMD, `file` is of type `char**` not `file[i]`. `file[i]` is of type `char*`.

Comment: @AMD, `*file[i]` would be a `char`.